# Suitable RFID module and tag for long range Read and Writablity

Tags: arduino

I want to make an attendance system for students where attendance is registered when RFID tag is scanned. However I wanted to know if there is a way to read and write on rfid tags within a range of 3 meters.
I did some research and came to a conclusion that high frequency battery powered passive tags would do the work... But I had a doubt about which rfid module version to be bought so that it could work with BAP tags, connects with arduino, supports reading and writing on tags and offers a range up to 3 meters.
Also I couldn't find any feasible BAP tags.(in India)
Also do read range depends upon RFID module or the type of tag we are using.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this [site](https://skyrfid.com/RFID_Range.php) also at this [arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=116555.00). May help you

Comment: I want RFID module that connects with Arduino not standalone reader/writers.